# Explicitly printing the zeros of an impulse train to a text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, asynchronous, text

I am trying to create an impulse train in Javascript and save the result to a text file. 
I would like one entry per line, and I would like zeros to be explicitly written, which I can't get to work. Here is the working code for generating the impulse train.

```
function impulseGenerator(numberOfPoints, frequency){
    var zeroArray = [];
    impulseArray = new Array(100).fill(0);
    var numberOfOnes = Math.floor(numberOfPoints/frequency);
    for(var i=0;i<numberOfPoints;i+=numberOfOnes){
        impulseArray[i]=1;
    }
    return impulseArray;
}
console.log(impulseGenerator(4000,400));
```

//the following code creates a text file in the "one entry per line" fashion that I desire, but it stops writing zeros after a while, instead leaving blank space in lieu of zeros.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('impulseTrain.txt', impulseTrain.join('\n'), (err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Extract saved successful');
});
```

How can I fix my code?

Thanks,
Nakul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main issue about your code was array construction. you are only filling 100 elements with zeros. however later you are adding extra length to array by setting array elements by index. as you are not going through every index, you leave some array elements `undefined`.

when trying to join the array elements, you only take care of not `undefined` elements (`undefined`, `null`, `[]` are converted to `''` according to `Array.prototype.join()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)), so the string comes into a sequence of '1's in a while.

i've also noticed your code might be working in a different logic to one you are trying to achieve according your variables names. you're using `numberOfOnes` as frequency to put '1' in the array.

here is the example of implementation:

```js
const generateImpulse = (length, frequency) => Array.apply(null, { length }).map((_, index) => !(index % frequency) ? 1 : 0);

console.log(generateImpulse(16, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not filling the array "correctly" in terms of its desired length.
A simple, old-school for-loop implementation to generate an array with `numberOfPoints` points with every  `frequency`'th value set to 1, the others to 0:

```
function impulseGenerator(numberOfPoints, frequency){
  var impulseArray = new Array(numberOfPoints);
  for (var i = 0; i < impulseArray.length; i++) {
    impulseArray[i] = (i % frequency == 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return impulseArray;
}
```